# C# Regex get specific character with decimal number

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex which return specific character with a decimal number up to 1 place

I have string text

```
(AvgC20.1 > 980000) && (C1>C2) MaxC20 MinC20.14
```

after applying regex get the following result

```
AvgC20, MaxC20, MinC20
```

This is the regex I am using

```
(Avg|Max|Min)[OHLVC]\d+
```

which return what I want but not return the decimal number up to one place

but I need result like this

```
AvgC20.1, MaxC20, MinC20.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an optional `(?:\.\d+)?` matching 1 or 0 occurrences of a `.` followed with 1 or more digits:

```
(?:Avg|Max|Min)[OHLVC]\d+(?:\.\d+)?
                         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3aAvg%7cMax%7cMin)%5bOHLVC%5d%5cd%2b(%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%2b)%3f&i=(AvgC20.1+%3e+980000)+%26%26+(C1%3eC2)+MaxC20+MinC20.14)

[image]

The `(?:...)?` is an optional [*non-capturing* group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group). It is optional (=matches one or zero occurrences) due to the `?` quantifier (a greedy one, that is why I mention *one or zero*, not *zero or one*). The non-capturing group is used for grouping purposes, without creating a buffer for the captured value in the memory. I suggested using the *non*-capturing group because the final result should be equal to the *whole match value*, so, no need tracking and storing those subvalues.

**NOTE on the non/capturing groups in .NET**: In .NET code, you can actually use numbered capturing groups and make them non-capturing by using the [`RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx) flag. Then, memory buffers will get created only for named capturing groups (like `(?<gr1>...)`).

**Pattern details**:

- `(?:Avg|Max|Min)` -  Either `Avg`, `Max` or `Min`
- `[OHLVC]` - one uppercase letter from the set
- `\d+` -  1 or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional sequence of a `.` followed with 1 or more digits.

Sidenote: it is best practice to disallow branches of the same alternation group to match at one and the same location, and `(?:Avg|Max|Min)` is better written as `(?:Avg|M(?:ax|in))`. However, what is good for the machine is not that fine for a human eye, so due to readability reasons, I'd advise to keep the first group as is.

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/L7uTyR) (note that the `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` is passed with the help of the inline `(?n)` option):

```
var s = "(AvgC20.1 > 980000) && (C1>C2) MaxC20 MinC20.14";
var pattern = @"(?n)(Avg|Max|Min)[OHLVC]\d+(\.\d+)?";
var result = Regex.Matches(s, pattern)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(p => p.Value)
        .ToList();
foreach (var r in result) // Demo printing the results
    Console.WriteLine(r);
```

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why `?:` is needed. Beginners won't know that parentheses are more than just a way to group characters

Comment: \d+ should be \d?

Comment: @HaseebKhan: You mean that uppercase letter is optional? Add a `?` after it. See [`(?:Avg|Max|Min)[OHLVC]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3aAvg%7cMax%7cMin)%5bOHLVC%5d%3f%5cd%2b(%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%2b)%3f&i=(AvgC20+%3e+980000)+%26%26+(C1%3eC2)+MaxC20+MinC20.14+Min40.1)

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew how to extract number after decimal only using regex. I have a number like 40.2 I just need to extract 2 using regex

Comment: See http://ideone.com/xZfdv7, use additional group, e.g. `@"(?n)(Avg|Max|Min)[OHLVC]\d+(\.(?<decimal>\d+))?"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you tell me how to extract only integer number (non decimal ) from a string.I have a string like

(778.25 -85.63) > 45000

after applying regex I just need 45000. what's the appropriate regex for that?

Comment: Use `@"(?<!\.)\d+(?!\.\d)"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew check here its not matching integer only also capturing decimal number.
http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5c.)%5cd%2b(%3f!%5c.%5cd)&i=(778.25+-85.63)+%3e+45000

Comment: Yes, add word boundaries - `(?<!\.)\b\d+\b(?!\.\d)`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew this is a regex which is used to select only constant number like 5,6,100. How can I include positive and negative sign +/-.
@"(?<!\.)\b\d+\b(?!\.\d)"

I need to select negative and positive number with sign as well

+100, -100, -50 +78

Comment: Add them - `(?<!\.)[-+]?\b\d+\b(?!\.\d)`

Comment: Thank you very much for such prompt response.